# How to create fixed footor view appear in all screens view controller , not footor tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

How to make footor uiview appear in all screens but I don't need footor as tableview or collection view I know that but need add fixed footor view entire for all screens ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the viewController has method for footer, i am really not sure.What I would do is:

I would create a customView and I will add this customView to the bottom of   all screens viewController as you want.